# Links cookie location

Tags: linux, cookies

Where does the Linux command line web browser `links` store its cookies? I'm writing a program that waits for a cookie from one of my websites to be saved before continuing with its execution. I believe all cookies are deleted when the browser is closed, but my program should still have time to find it (polling continuously) before the user exits. I just need to know where to look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least in [this edition of links](http://links.twibright.com/development.php) (the source for the links and links2 packages on Debian), links doesn't actually save the cookies anywhere persistent – it simply keeps them in a RAM-backed data structure.

For what it's worth, though, [elinks](http://elinks.cz/) stores cookies on disk – specifically, in ~/.elinks/cookies.